# How can I write an IO [String] to stdout?

Tags: haskell, io

I have an `IO [String]` in `main`, which I want to write (as lines) to stdout. How?

--newbie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IO [String]` is an action that will get you strings.  If you wish to perform the action and print the results then consider:

```
printIOString io = putStrLn . unlines =<< io
```

Or with some additional notation, if you prefer:

```
printIOString io =
  do strs <- io
     let rendered = unlines strs
     putStrLn rendered
```